# How can I make a Python function examine every element of a list?

Tags: python

I was ordered to build a Bulean Function that takes a list of numbers and execute "True" if the list is a proper grade list(i.e every number is between 0 to 100) and "False" otherwise. I however encounter Error, caused, I believe by my not very thorough acquaintance with the program. The reason why I ask here is that I mostly learn by doing.

I tried few scripts. This is one of them:

```
 def IsValidGradeList(I):
    for x in range(0,len(I)+1):
        if I[x] not in range (0,101):
            return False
        else: continue
        return True
```

As I see, the code won't look the way it does in the scripter. How can I attend it?
I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you all for your help. Unfortunately, I am not to use "all" built-in function yet, for we've not learned how to properly use it. This is, however, what I've done so far. It seems to be working.

```
def AreIntegers(I):
    x=0
    for x in range(0,len(I)):
        if type(I[x])==int:
            x=x+1
        else:
                return False
    return True

def IsBounded(I):
    x=0
    for x in range(0,len(I)):
        if I[x] in range(0,101):
            x=x+1
        else:
                return False
    return True

def IsValidGradeList(I):
    if IsBounded(I)==True:
        if AreIntegers(I)==True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I have asked then:where am I specifically exceeding the regulations? I have read those guidelines but I fear I didn't understand them all for they are High level English to me and I am having troubles fully understand them.

Comment: Thank you. I shall get it fixed.

Comment: Are non-integer grades allowed?

Comment: Could you give us a sample input and expected output?

Comment: In the new code you've added `x=x+1` does not actually do anything useful and could be replaced with `continue`. These functions may work (if the indentation is fixed) but are unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I thought they are. This is my very first exercise and I am very limited in what I am allowed to use. If it does work that is fine by me. I shall try continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needs to go through the list and if it catches a grade that is outside the range 0-100, return `False`. If it does not catch any such grade it continues until it reaches the end of the list. At that point we know that none of the grades are outside of the range so can return `True`. So, simply unindenting `return True` so that it is executed after the loop has finished would make your code work.

```
def IsValidGradeList(I):
    for x in range(0,len(I)+1):
        if I[x] not in range (0,101):
            return False
        else: continue
    return True    # This needs to be *outside* of the for loop
```

This can be simplified a bit: the `continue` statement doesn't do anything; you can loop through the elements of the list rather than using an index; and you can check grades are within a range using the form `a <= x <= b` rather than with `range`.

```
def is_valid_grade_list(L):
    for grade in L:
        if not 0 <= grade <= 100:
            return False
    return True
```

And `all` provides a shortcut for this type of function:

```
def is_valid_grade_list(L):
    return all(0 <= grade <= 100 for grade in L)
```

If you need to check that each grade is an integer as well as checking that it is within range, you can just add `isinstance(grade, int)` to the condition:

```
def is_valid_grade_list(L):
    for grade in L:
        if not (isinstance(grade, int) and 0 <= grade <= 100):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Since the OP had the right idea, and this solution looks (to a new programmer) to be pretty similar, maybe an explanation as to *why* this is the right answer. The difference is that `return True` was getting called after the *first* element in for the OP, but you correctly wait until the end.

Comment: @dwanderson edited to try and explain. The OP code actually almost works.

Answer (score 0):

```
is_valid_grade_list = all([x in xrange(0, 101) for x in grade_list])
```

Comment: I am still looking for a way of bypassing that method for we haven't learned it, but I will when I have comprehended it. :)

Comment: This is probably the most concise and readable form available in Python. If your homework imposes artificial constraints on the solution, just implement `all` as a helper function,

Answer (score 0):

How about a list comprehension (without looking at your sample input data)?

```
all([False if I[x] not in range(0, 101) else True for x in range(0, len(I)+1)])
```